# Question regarding definition of Universally Closed mapping

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was reading Algebraic Geometry by Hartshorne, and I saw a statement, which says a universal closed mapping is closed.

Now, what I know the definition of Universally closed is from Toric Variety By Cox et. al that if $X \rightarrow Y$ is universally closed, then for any variety $Z$ and any morphism $\phi:Z \rightarrow Y$, the projection mapping $\pi:X\times_Y Z \rightarrow Z$ is closed. I don't understand how this definition of Universal mapping Implies that this mapping is closed. It will be great if you can help me about this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the universal closure condition to the variety $Z = Y$ and the morphism $\phi$ as the identity on $Y$.